# Compatible conditions on first fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

The fundamental theorem of surface theory asserts that the existence of a simply connected surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose first and second fundamental forms are $I$ and $II$, if the coefficients ($g_{ij}$) and ($h_{ij}$) of $I$ and $II$ satisfy the Gauss-Codazzi system.

Now if we only consider a given symmetric positive definite $2\times2$ matrix $g=(g_{ij})$, can we find compatible conditions only on $g$, such that $g$ is the first fundamental form of a simply connected surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Say, we need the existence of parametrization $y:\omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\nabla y^T\nabla y=g$.

Comment: For a surface the coefficients $(g_{ij})$ and $(h_{ij})$ depend on the point on the surface, so they are actually functions. These functions are not constant unless your surface is the standard sphere. How do you want that to equal a single given $2 \times 2$ matrix?

Comment: @quarague The given $2\times2$ matrix is a function here, and it is not constant in general.